# Textures not working (Black Textures) - OpenGL + GLSL

Tags: opengl

I am trying to detect silhouette edges and render some textures (varies based on the diffuse term) on these edges using OpenGL and shaders. I am rendering a quad using the geometry shader and also assign the texture coordinates here. In the fragment shader, i am trying to use the diffuse term calculated in vertex shader to render different textures based on diffTerm's value. There are two issues with my code.

1) The diffuse term should vary from (-1,1) but it seems to be stuck at 0 when i rotate the model and it reaches negative values at certain positions.

2) The textures are always black and I cant seem to find out what is causing this issue.

"MeshViewer.cpp" - The main file

```
Mesh* mesh;
GLuint* texID = new GLuint[5];
float rotn_x = 0.0, rotn_y = 0.0, fov;
GLuint matrixLoc1, matrixLoc2, matrixLoc3,texLoc1, texLoc2, texLoc3, texLoc4, texLoc5;
float cam_near, cam_far;    //Near and far planes of the camera
const float PI = 3.14159265f;
glm::mat4 view;   //View and projection matrices

void loadTextures()
{
glGenTextures(5, texID);   //Generate 1 texture ID
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);  //Texture unit 0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID[0]);
loadTGA("Pencil0.tga");
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);  //Texture unit 0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID[1]);
loadTGA("Pencil1.tga");
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);  //Texture unit 0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID[2]);
loadTGA("Pencil2.tga");
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);  //Texture unit 0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID[3]);
loadTGA("Brick.tga");
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);  //Texture unit 0
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID[4]);
loadTGA("Brick.tga");
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}
void initialise()
{
// --- Mesh object ---
GLuint lgtLoc;
mesh = new Mesh();
if(!mesh->loadMeshOFF("Camel.off")) cout << "Error reading mesh data file." << endl;

//  --- Camera parameters ---
float win_width = (mesh->_xmax - mesh->_xmin) * 1.5f;
float win_height = (mesh->_ymax - mesh->_ymin) * 1.5f;
if(win_width > win_height)  win_height = win_width;    //Maintain aspect ratio = 1
cam_near = 2*(mesh->_zmax) - mesh->_zmin;
cam_far =  2*(mesh->_zmin) - mesh->_zmax;
float cam_posx = (mesh->_xmax + mesh->_xmin) * 0.5f;
float cam_posy = (mesh->_ymax + mesh->_ymin) * 0.5f;
float cam_posz = cam_near + win_height;
fov = 27.0f;                                //Approx. atan(0.5)

// --- Uniform locations ---
GLuint program = createShaderProg("MeshViewer.vert", "MeshViewer.frag", "MeshViewer.geom");
matrixLoc1 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mvMatrix");
matrixLoc2 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mvpMatrix");
matrixLoc3 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "norMatrix");
lgtLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "lightPos");

GLint lineWidth = glGetUniformLocation(program, "HalfWidth");
if (lineWidth > -1)
    glUniform1f(lineWidth, 0.005f);
GLint overhangLength = glGetUniformLocation(program, "OverhangLength");
if (overhangLength > -1)
    glUniform1f(overhangLength, 0.15f);

texLoc1 = glGetUniformLocation (program, "tex1"); 
glUniform1i(texLoc1, 0);
texLoc2 = glGetUniformLocation (program, "tex2"); 
glUniform1i(texLoc2, 1);
texLoc3 = glGetUniformLocation (program, "tex3"); 
glUniform1i(texLoc3, 2);
texLoc4 = glGetUniformLocation (program, "tex4"); 
glUniform1i(texLoc4, 3);
texLoc5 = glGetUniformLocation (program, "tex5"); 
glUniform1i(texLoc5, 4);


view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(cam_posx, cam_posy, cam_posz), glm::vec3(cam_posx, cam_posy, 0.0),         glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)); //view matrix
glm::vec4 light = glm::vec4(100.0, 50.0, 100.0, 1.0);             //Light's position
glm::vec4 lightEye = view*light;     //Light position in eye coordinates
glUniform4fv(lgtLoc, 1, &lightEye[0]);

// --- OpenGL  ---
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);       
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);   //Wireframe
mesh->setColor(0, 0, 1);                    //Mesh color = blue.

mesh->createVAO();   //Create buffer objects for the mesh
}


void display()  
{
glm::mat4 proj;
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

glm::mat4 matrix = glm::mat4(1.0);
matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, rotn_x, glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));  //rotation about x
matrix = glm::rotate(matrix, rotn_y, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));  //rotation about y
glm::mat4 prodMatrix1 = view*matrix;        //Model-view matrix
proj = glm::perspective(fov, 1.0f, cam_near, cam_far);  //perspective projection matrix
glm::mat4 prodMatrix2 = proj*prodMatrix1;   //The model-view-projection transformation
glm::mat4 invMatrix = glm::inverse(prodMatrix1);  //Inverse of model-view matrix for normal transformation
glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixLoc1, 1, GL_FALSE, &prodMatrix1[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixLoc2, 1, GL_FALSE, &prodMatrix2[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixLoc3, 1, GL_TRUE, &invMatrix[0][0]);  //Use transpose matrix here

mesh->render();

glFlush();
}


void specialKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
if(key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) rotn_y -= 5.0;
else if(key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) rotn_y += 5.0;
else if(key == GLUT_KEY_UP) rotn_x -= 5.0;
else if(key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) rotn_x += 5.0;
else if(key == GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP) fov --;
else if(key == GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN) fov ++;
if(fov < 1.0) fov = 1.0;
else if(fov > 80.0) fov = 80.0;
glutPostRedisplay();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize (600, 600); 
glutInitWindowPosition (20, 10);
glutCreateWindow ("Mesh Viewer");
glutInitContextVersion (4, 2);
glutInitContextProfile ( GLUT_CORE_PROFILE );

if(glewInit() == GLEW_OK)
{
    cout << "GLEW initialization successful! " << endl;
    cout << " Using GLEW version " << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION) << endl;
}
else
{
    cerr << "Unable to initialize GLEW  ...exiting." << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
initialise ();
glutDisplayFunc(display); 
glutSpecialFunc(specialKeys);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 cols;
layout (location = 3) in vec2 texC;

uniform mat4 mvMatrix;
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 norMatrix;
uniform vec4 lightPos;
out float diffTerm;
out vec4 vColour;
out float viewTerm;
out float silhoutte;
out vec2 TexC;

void main()
{
vec4 grey = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
vec4 posnEye = mvMatrix * position;
vec4 normalEye = norMatrix * vec4(normal, 0);
vec4 lgtVec = normalize(lightPos - posnEye);  
vec4 viewVec = normalize(vec4(-posnEye.xyz, 0)); 
float viewTerm = max(dot(viewVec, normalEye),0);
vec4 material = vec4(cols, 1.0);
vec4 lgtAmb = grey * material;
diffTerm = max(dot(lgtVec, normalEye), 0);
vec4 lgtDiff = material * diffTerm;
silhoutte = dot(viewVec, normalEye);
gl_Position = mvpMatrix * position;
vColour = vec4(cols, 1);
TexC = texC;
}
```

Geometry Shader:

```
#version 430 core


layout(triangles_adjacency) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 6) out;
in vec2 texC[];
out vec2 TexCoord;
in vec4 vColour[];
out vec4 colorv;
in float viewTerm[];
out float viewTermg;
in float diffTerm[];
out float diffTermg;
in vec2 TexC[];
out vec2 TexCg;
uniform float HalfWidth;
uniform float OverhangLength;
out float gDist;
out vec3 gSpine;

bool IsFront(vec3 A, vec3 B, vec3 C)
{
float area = (A.x * B.y - B.x * A.y) + (B.x * C.y - C.x * B.y) + (C.x * A.y - A.x * C.y);
return area > 0;
}

void EmitEdge(vec3 P0, vec3 P1)
{
vec3  E = OverhangLength * vec3(P1.xy - P0.xy, 0);
vec2  V = normalize(E.xy);
vec3  N = vec3(-V.y, V.x, 0) * 0.005;
vec3  S = -N;
float D = HalfWidth;

gSpine = P0;
gl_Position = vec4(P0 + S - E, 1); gDist = +D; TexCoord=vec2(0.0,0.0); colorv = vColour[0];     EmitVertex();
gl_Position = vec4(P0 + N - E, 1); gDist = -D; TexCoord=vec2(1.0,0.0); colorv = vColour[1]; EmitVertex();
gSpine = P1;
gl_Position = vec4(P1 + S + E, 1); gDist = +D; TexCoord=vec2(1.0,1.0); colorv = vColour[0]; EmitVertex();
gl_Position = vec4(P1 + N + E, 1); gDist = -D; ; TexCoord=vec2(0.0,1.0); EmitVertex();
EndPrimitive();
}

void main()
{
vec3 v0 = gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz / gl_in[0].gl_Position.w;
vec3 v1 = gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz / gl_in[1].gl_Position.w;
vec3 v2 = gl_in[2].gl_Position.xyz / gl_in[2].gl_Position.w;
vec3 v3 = gl_in[3].gl_Position.xyz / gl_in[3].gl_Position.w;
vec3 v4 = gl_in[4].gl_Position.xyz / gl_in[4].gl_Position.w;
vec3 v5 = gl_in[5].gl_Position.xyz / gl_in[5].gl_Position.w;

if (IsFront(v0, v2, v4)) {
    if (!IsFront(v0, v1, v2)) EmitEdge(v0, v2);
    //if (!IsFront(v2, v3, v4)) EmitEdge(v2, v4);
    //if (!IsFront(v0, v4, v5)) EmitEdge(v4, v0);
} 

}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330

in vec4 vColourg;
in float diffTermg;
in float silhoutte;
in vec2 TexCg;
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform sampler2D tex2;
uniform sampler2D tex3;
uniform sampler2D tex4;
uniform sampler2D tex5;

void main()
{



vec4 texColor1 = texture(tex1, TexCoord);
vec4 texColor2 = texture(tex2, TexCoord);
vec4 texColor3 = texture(tex3, TexCoord);
vec4 texColor4 = texture(tex4, TexCoord);
vec4 texColor5 = texture(tex5, TexCoord);

vec4 blue = vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
vec4 red = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
vec4 yellow = vec4(1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0);


if (diffTermg<0)
{
gl_FragColor = blue;
}
else if (diffTermg ==0)
{
gl_FragColor = texColor5;
}
else if (diffTermg > 0 && diffTermg < 0.2)
gl_FragColor = yellow;
else if (diffTermg > 100)
gl_FragColor = blue;

}
```

**EDIT:**
Shader.h

```
GLuint loadShader(GLenum shaderType, string filename)
{
ifstream shaderFile(filename.c_str());
if(!shaderFile.good()) cout << "Error opening shader file." << endl;
stringstream shaderData;
shaderData << shaderFile.rdbuf();
shaderFile.close();
string shaderStr = shaderData.str();
const char* shaderTxt = shaderStr.c_str();

GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shaderTxt, NULL);
glCompileShader(shader);
GLint status;
glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
if (status == GL_FALSE)
{
    GLint infoLogLength;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
    GLchar *strInfoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);
    const char *strShaderType = NULL;
    cerr <<  "Compile failure in shader: " << strInfoLog << endl;
    delete[] strInfoLog;
}
return shader;
}

GLuint createShaderProg(string vertShader, string fragShader, string geomShader)
{
GLuint shaderv = loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertShader);
GLuint shaderf = loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragShader);
GLuint shaderg = loadShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER, geomShader);

GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, shaderv);
glAttachShader(program, shaderf);
glAttachShader(program, shaderg);
glLinkProgram(program);

GLint status;
glGetProgramiv (program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
if (status == GL_FALSE)
{
    GLint infoLogLength;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
    GLchar *strInfoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);
    fprintf(stderr, "Linker failure: %s\n", strInfoLog);
    delete[] strInfoLog;
    program = 0;
}
glUseProgram(program);
return program;
}
```

loadTGA.h

```
void loadTGA(string filename)
{
char id, cmap, imgtype, bpp, c_garb;
char* imageData, temp;
short int s_garb, wid, hgt;
int nbytes, size, indx;
ifstream file( filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
if(!file)
{
    cout << "*** Error opening image file: " << filename.c_str() << endl;
    exit(1);
}
file.read (&id, 1);
file.read (&cmap, 1);
file.read (&imgtype, 1);    
if(imgtype != 2 && imgtype != 3 )   //2= colour (uncompressed),  3 = greyscale (uncompressed)
{
    cout << "*** Incompatible image type: " << (int)imgtype << endl;
    exit(1);
}
//Color map specification
file.read ((char*)&s_garb, 2);
file.read ((char*)&s_garb, 2);
file.read (&c_garb, 1);
//Image specification
file.read ((char*)&s_garb, 2);  //x origin
file.read ((char*)&s_garb, 2);  //y origin
file.read ((char*)&wid, 2);     //image width                                   
file.read ((char*)&hgt, 2);     //image height
file.read (&bpp, 1);     //bits per pixel
file.read (&c_garb, 1);  //img descriptor
nbytes = bpp / 8;           //No. of bytes per pixels
size = wid * hgt * nbytes;  //Total number of bytes to be read
imageData = new char[size];
file.read(imageData, size);
//cout << ">>>" << nbytes << " " << wid << " " << hgt << endl;
if(nbytes > 2)   //swap R and B
{
    for(int i = 0; i < wid*hgt;  i++)
    {
        indx = i*nbytes;
        temp = imageData[indx];
        imageData[indx] = imageData[indx+2];
        imageData[indx+2] = temp;
    }
}

switch (nbytes)
{
     case 1:
         glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 1, wid, hgt, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
         break;
     case 3:
         glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, wid, hgt, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
         break;
     case 4:
         glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, wid, hgt, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
         break;
 }
 delete imageData;                       
}
```

Comment: Where do you activate your shader program (e.g. glUseProgram())?

Comment: @AntonAngelov: i have added the header file that does the loading of shaders.. It contains the glUseProgram()..

Comment: I can't see where you load your textures, but I assume you do it correctly. Just an idea, you can set fragment shader's color to show the UV coords (just you can know if the problem comes from texture or coords). Another thing: if the diffuse term is stuck at 0, means that either your light vector or normal vector isn't correct. "vec4 lgtVec = normalize(lightPos - posnEye);" Here your light vector is pointing from the LightPos(perhaps worldspace) to Vertex(camera space), and Lambert's diffuse term requires L to be the reverse vector (from vertex to light source [in same space]).Just a thought.

Comment: @AntonAngelov: the texture coordinates seem to be working properly.. the problem is with the textures. Though, i cant figure what the problem is with the loading of textures. The same function works well with other programs. And thanks for your advice!!!

Comment: @AntonAngelov  I found out what my mistake was.. It was a silly mistake of not calling the loadTextures() function in my initialise() function.. Now the textures seems to be working..

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting a core profile context:

```
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

But your `glTexImage2D()` calls are not compatible with the core profile:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 1, wid, hgt, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, wid, hgt, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, wid, hgt, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
```

Using the number of components as the internal format (argument 3) is legacy from OpenGL 1.0, and was finally eliminated when the core profile was introduced. `GL_LUMINANCE` is also gone. The modern (core profile) equivalent of those calls is:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, wid, hgt, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, wid, hgt, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, wid, hgt, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
```

The post contains a lot of code, and I did not study it in detail to see if there are other problems. I strongly recommend the use of `glGetError()`, which would have reported these invalid arguments, and should also be helpful to check if there are any additional problems.